# Can't we include vars in gorilla subrouter pathprefix?

Tags: go, routes, gorilla, mux

I'm trying to add a subrouter to my router code :

```golang
router := mux.NewRouter()
baseRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()
managementRouter := baseRouter.PathPrefix("/managing/{id}").Subrouter()
managementRouter.Use(auth.ManagingMiddleware)
managementRouter.HandleFunc("/add-employees", management.AddEmployeesToOrganization).Methods("POST")
```

The goal is to force the client to give an `id` variable on each call to `managementRouter`
functions.
Although, when i send a request like this :

```
/api/v1/managing/627e6f7e05db3552970e1164/add-employees
```

... I get a 404. Am I missing something or is it just not possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution in my dream last night haha

Basically the problem with the following prefix :

```golang
managementRouter := baseRouter.PathPrefix("/managing/{id}").Subrouter()
```

Is that the router has no way of knowing where the `id` field stops. So when we access an endpoint with for example this url : `/api/v1/managing/627e6f7e05db3552970e1164/add-employees`, the router believes that the `{id}` variable is literally `627e6f7e05db3552970e1164/add-employees` and doesn't match any route after it.

So the solution I found is to tell the router what comes after the variable. For that, you just add a slash after the variable :

```golang
managementRouter := baseRouter.PathPrefix("/managing/{id}/").Subrouter()
```